# seaborn how to set style and font size

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I am trying to change both style and font size like this

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid")  

sns.set(font_scale=1.5)
```

But it seems that both are mutually exclusive. I can use only 
one of the lines at a time. How to make both changes apparent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put them both in the same [`seaborn.set`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set.html) command:

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid", font_scale=1.5)
```

As per the docs, `seaborn.set` is an alias for [`seaborn.set_theme`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_theme.html#seaborn.set_theme)

```
seaborn.set_theme(style="whitegrid", font_scale=1.5)
```